# ".directory" in home acceptable?

Tags: python, configuration

I'd like to save my script's data to disk to load next time the script runs. For simplicity, is it a good idea to use `os.path.expanduser('~')` and save a directory named ".myscript_data" there? It would only need to be read by the script, and to avoid clutter for the user, I'd like it to be hidden. Is it acceptable practice to place hidden ".files" on the users computer?

Comment: I think .files are not hidden under windows

Comment: @XavierCombelle I tried renaming a Windows folder ".x", and it said "I must supply a filename" or the like.

Comment: You can still create dotfiles/dotfolders in Windows using the command line. It's only Windows Explorer that won't let you make them. They won't be hidden, though; you still have to apply the hidden attribute if you want them to be invisible (this is what VCSs like SVN and git do to their .svn/.git directories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, use a subfolder of `os.environ['APPDATA']`; on Linux, a dot-folder under `$HOME` is typical.

You can also consider putting your files in a subdirectory of `~/.config`*, which is a sort of emerging standard for configuration file placement. See also the [XDG basefiles spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Not entirely related, but interesting: [origin of dotfiles](https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp)

*(edit) More accurately, `os.environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME', os.path.expanduser('~/.config'))` as per the XDG spec.

Comment: Ooo... I look forward to a world where everyone puts config files in `~/.config` instead of `~` ...

Comment: According to LSB (if I remember correctly) `$HOME/.config/$appname/` should be used for config files - `.$HOME/.$appname/` is considered legacy. Large amounts of data should not be placed there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. (I'm assuming you're on linux, right?)
See also [this](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/726/whats-the-equivalent-to-appdata-folder-in-linux).

Comment: I'm developing on Mac OS X, but I want it to be universal for unix-like. Windows support would be nice if I don't have to re-write the script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is standard practice on most Unix systems. For transparency, it's often a good idea to print an informative message like `Creating directory .dir to store script state` the first time you create the storage location.

If you are expecting to store significant amounts of data, it's a good idea to confirm the location with the user.

This is also the standard place for any additional configuration files for your application.

Comment: It's only about 5KB, so I think it will be fine. I'm working to make the script hyper-readable, so people can figure it out (and I'll include a preference to set the data storage location, showing `~/.mydata` as the default.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I suggest a file or directory (no dotfile) in `os.environ['XDG_CONFIG_HOME']`, which is in most cases the directory $HOME/.config. A dotfile in $HOME, however, is also often being used.